# How to link the uploaded artifacts to the release page in Github

Tags: github-actions

After upload-artifact, we can only download the artifacts in the page below.

I want to build a workflow, which can create a release page and link my artifacts in it.

So that every time after I push the code, users can download from the release page directly.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

[image]

```
name: MSBuild

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    tags:
        - "v*.*.*"
    

env:
  # Path to the solution file relative to the root of the project.
  SOLUTION_FILE_PATH: .
  QT_VERSION:   '6.4.3'
  ARTIFACT:     'xxx-build.zip'
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: 'Release'
  PROJ_NAME:    'xxx'
  

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
- name: Save build artifact
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  with:
       name: ${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
       path: ${{ runner.temp }}\build\${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
       if-no-files-found: error
       retention-days: 30

- name: Create a release
  uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
  with:
       files: |
              ${{ github.workspace }}/release/*
  env:
       GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

**Update2:**
I use the cmd:

`git tag -a v1.0.1 -m "test release"`

`git push origin v1.0.1`

And got this release page.

1. The artifacts are not correct. What I want is not the source code.
2. It seems like the workflow didn't be triggerred.

Thanks!

[image]

**Update3:**

1. I removed all tags, and now create a single tag "v1.0.0"

   `git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "test release"`

   `git push origin v1.0.0`
2. Manually trigger the workflow action
3. log:

   `Run softprops/action-gh-release@v1`

   `Error: ⚠️ GitHub Releases requires a tag`

**Update4:**

1. `git tag` and `git push` are two separate cmds but if I cannot push and give it a tag simultaneously, how can I trigger `if: github.ref_type == 'tag'` ?
2. I referred to this post and got an idea but still cannot give it a tag automatically.

> https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release/issues/270

```
- name: (9) Save build artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
           name: ${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
           path: ${{ runner.temp }}\build\${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
           if-no-files-found: error
           retention-days: 30

- name: (10) Tag the repository
  shell: bash
  id: tag
  run: |
        # See https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/dealing-with-special-characters-in-branch-and-tag-names
        TAG=v$(date -Iseconds | sed 's/[T:\+]/-/g')
        echo "$TAG"
        echo "tag=$TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        git config --global user.name "GitHub Action"
        git config --global user.email "xxx@xx.com"
        git tag -a $TAG -m "Published version $TAG" ${GITHUB_SHA}
        git push origin $TAG

- name: (11) Create a release
  # if: ${{ github.ref_type == 'tag' }}
  uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
  with:
    files: |
            ${{ runner.temp }}\build\${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
    tag_name: ${{ steps.tag.outputs.tag }}
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Also, I am still confused at this line in step (11):

```
files: |
        ${{ runner.temp }}\build\${{ env.ARTIFACT }}
```

If I already downloaded my built file in step (9), why I still need to access to the artifact from this path `${{ runner.temp }}\build\${{ env.ARTIFACT }}` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `softprops/action-gh-release` will take of adding artifacts to the release. Check your repo's Releases page if you've created a release already. The release artifacts should already be there.

Comment: Hi, I've added the `on` trigger section in my script. So, do you mean once I push the branch, the release page will show the artifacts below? Actually, I only see my source code (zip) below the Releases page. Do I need to modify `files` section in the `softprops/action-gh-release@v1`?

Comment: Hi! Please check the logs. It must be complaining that it didn't find any artifacts. Match the paths of your artifacts both for `actions/upload-artifact` and `softprops/action-gh-release`.

Comment: I only got the source code (zip), and the workflow didn;t be triggerred. I've updated the question, plz take a look.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of `softprops/action-gh-release`?

Comment: Hi, the workflow didn't be triggerred, so there's no log file...

Comment: Did you push another tag? Is your workflow valid? No issues in linting? The one in your question doesn't look complete (or at least it's not valid) i.e. indentation issues, missing `steps`, etc.

Comment: I removed all of my tags and re-create a single one, and now log shows Error: ⚠️ GitHub Releases requires a tag.

Comment: For normal commits, you need to skip the release step, Only run it if it's a tag e.g. `if: github.ref_type == 'tag'`. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. For normal commits, it should only build the code.  I know how to add the conditional expression, but `git tag...` may not triggers the workflow, right?

Comment: That's correct. `git tag` won't trigger the build but `git push` will. And, on the basis of the reference type,`branch` or `tag`, you can adjust your workflow accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to give my commit a tag automatically, but still can not create a release page.

Comment: What do you mean "**give my commit a tag automatically**"? Generating tag from CI workflow?